# Popular question with bounty - no comments and answers

Tags: discussion, questions, bounty

I had a question with just a few views (4-5) and then I've set a bounty and now bounty is ending. Question now has a lot of views and vote ups, but no comments and answers.

1. So where will go my bounty of 50 reputation?
2. Can I add more bounty to an existing bounty?
3. Is it make sense to add new bounty?
4. How to ask someone who has voted to set bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212670/avaudioplayer-preloaded-sound-leaks-from-memory) question then I would suggest the following.

There are several different problem asked in the question. It is better to write about one clearly stated problem per question.

There are several confusing phrases in the question making it hard to understand what you are asking. (Whilst I know nothing about the topics in your question, I can see that the wording could be much clearer.) Here are some examples:

> then after a few [what] start playing it
>
> it leaks from memory and I is not being prepared
>
> After that fed hours
>
> But them main question

My recommendation is to reword the question to make the problems clearer. Possibly change from one question to several questions. I would reccommend against adding another bonus at this time.